# My Input field are losing focus when type 1 character in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please don't unvoted me, I knew it has so many similar question. I tried all of that but It doesn't work for me. TT

I have some problem with rendering of ReactJS. When I typing every character input field will lost focus. I don't know why it was that. Maybe someone help me ?

I already try to put some different key on input tag because I seen this solution from other people question but It doesn't work.

```
class AddUpdatePage extends Component {
    state = {
        nameOfPage: ""
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <BaseInput
                key="baseInput1"
                title="Test"
                placeholder="Test"
                name="nameOfPage"
                value={this.state.nameOfPage}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />

        );
    }
}
```

and

```
class BaseInput extends Component {
    state = {}

    render() {
        let {
             title,
             placeholder,
             onChange,
             value,
             name} = this.props
        return (
            <div className="base-input-wrapper" key={key}>
                <BaseTitle>{title ? title : "title"}</BaseTitle>
                <div className="input-wrapper-normal">
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        className="base-input" 
                        name={name} 
                        onChange={onChange} 
                        value={value} 
                        placeholder={placeholder}></input>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

 export default BaseInput;
```

Comment: Comment this line `e.preventDefault();` from handleChange() and onChange() functions

Comment: @iSahilSharma **I tried already but It doesn't work too**. thx for your comment.

Comment: Remove `key={Math.random()}` and `key={key}` in your `BaseInput` component, you don't need those. `Math.random()` causes this probably in your code.

Comment: @iSahilSharma **I updated question's code already, please look again.**

Comment: @devserkan It's still not working** . but thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@devserkan is right, every time you change the state, the input is rendered again, and since you added `key={Math.random()}` react loses the reference to it.

Here is an example working by just removing the keys

https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-worker-yfhbm?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `key`s everywhere you like, you should use them when you map your elements and you need to find proper unique values by using those elements. You shouldn't create them on the fly as you do with `Math.random()` there.

Also, you can't pass a `key` as a prop to your components, this does not work. So, here is a working example.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    nameOfPage: ""
  };

  handleChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BaseInput
          title="Test"
          placeholder="Test"
          name="nameOfPage"
          value={this.state.nameOfPage}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        {this.state.nameOfPage && JSON.stringify(this.state.nameOfPage)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function BaseInput(props) {
  let { placeholder, onChange, value, name } = props;

  return (
    <div className="base-input-wrapper">
      <div className="input-wrapper-normal">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="base-input"
          name={name}
          onChange={onChange}
          value={value}
          placeholder={placeholder}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Which global variable are you referring to my example @YevgenGorbunkov ?

Comment: Ah, I guess you assumed that `state = {}` is a global variable. It would be nice reading about [class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your helping. Now I found solution already. I missing to post the parent  . The parent div of .. is  that I made for be a container wrapper and styled it by use style component that cause a problem.

Sorry for wasted everyone's time. In actually my code is be like below. but I shorted code for easy to read.

```
<ContainerEz>
   <BaseInput ..... />
</ContainerEz>
```

In containerEz, I used a styled component like this.

```
const ContainerEz = ({ children,
                       isLessonHeader,
                       isCourseList,
                       isTemplate }) => {

    const Wrapper = styled.div`
        padding: 0 20px;
        width: 100%;
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            padding: 0 60px;
        }
    `;

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            {children}
        </Wrapper>
    );
}
```

I moved a **Wrapper** to outside function and everything are find ~

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
        padding: 0 20px;
        width: 100%;
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            padding: 0 60px;
        }
`;

const ContainerEz = ({ children, isLessonHeader, isCourseList, isTemplate }) => {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            {children}
        </>
    );
}
```